# 'RawQuerySet' object has no attribute 'distinct'

Tags: sql-server, django

I have this django raw query `User.objects.raw("Select distinct * from users")` but it brings

> 'RawQuerySet' object has no attribute 'distinct'.

What could be the problem and the solution?

Comment: Have you tried using Django's built-in support `User.objects.distinct()`?

Comment: Yes it works, but i wanted through raw query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happened when Django fails to return a class object from the raw query. This means that Django only returns the queryset results without mapping to the class object.